# Set environment variable with PowerShell as if it were done from the UI

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I've been trying to set the PATH environment variable with PowerShell for a while now with partial success.
The best I've got so far is to use SETX, which sets the proper value type in the registry, eg REG_EXPAND_SZ, and it also broadcasts the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message to notify all current windows.
I'm running the command as Administrator to be able to change the path to the machine level. Now the problem is that only console run as Administrator will expand variables, but if I force an edit of the PATH variable through the Windows UI, then any console will be able to expand the variables.
Any idea what is that the UI is doing that SETX doesn't?

Comment: Don't think this has much to do with PowerShell. Have a read here [What is the difference between SETX and SET in environment variables in windows](http://superuser.com/questions/916649/what-is-the-difference-between-setx-and-set-in-environment-variables-in-windows)

Comment: Thank you Jan, I'm aware of the difference and I need the change to be permanent and the variables to be expanded for all users (not only for my users when running as Administrator).